# how to use seq function of r in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want of sequence of values to be written on new column based on previous columns

this is my dataframe df

```
a  b
11 15
32 35
```

i want output to be like this

```
a  b   c
11 15  11,12,13,14
32 35  32,33,34
```

it should get sequence from first two columns

my code

```
df.apply(lambda x : range(x['a'],x['b']),1)
```

it gives me some thing like this
not able to remove paranthesis  and split by comma into multiple rows

```
a  b   c
11 15  (11,12,13,14)
32 35  (32,33,34)
```

Comment: Sorry, now  I am confused - accepted by accident? Because your expected ouput is different like accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you want to convert the values into rows you can do it from the generated tuple using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Otherwise @jezrael answer should work fine for you.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[11, 15],[32, 35]],columns=['a','b'])
df['c']= df.apply(lambda x : range(x['a'],x['b']),1)

df.explode('c')
```

Out:

```
    a   b   c
0  11  15  11
0  11  15  12
0  11  15  13
0  11  15  14
1  32  35  32
1  32  35  33
1  32  35  34
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert values to strings and join by `join`:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x : ','.join(str(i) for i in range(x['a'],x['b'])),1)
#alternative
#df['c'] = [','.join(str(i) for i in range(x,y)) for x, y in df[['a','b']].to_numpy()]
```

Or:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x : ','.join(map(str, range(x['a'],x['b']))),1)
#alternative
#df['c'] = [','.join(map(str, range(x,y))) for x, y in df[['a','b']].to_numpy()]
```

---

```
print (df)
    a   b            c
0  11  15  11,12,13,14
1  32  35     32,33,34
```

EDIT: For new rows use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['c']= df.apply(lambda x : range(x['a'],x['b']),1)

df = df.explode('c').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
    a   b   c
0  11  15  11
1  11  15  12
2  11  15  13
3  11  15  14
4  32  35  32
5  32  35  33
6  32  35  34
```

Comment: Good morning @jezrael.